# PHP script to select MySQL data fields and return JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

So I am trying to download JSON into an iOS application and I don't really know a lot about PHP.

Currently I'm using a generic php scrip as a delegate that connects the the MySQL database and returns JSON results.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //database host server
$db = "***"; //database name
$user = "root"; //database user
$pass = "root"; //password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db("***", $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;        
        }

        //Output the data as JSON

        echo json_encode($records);

    }


}


?>
```

The issue with this is that I don't want to encode the entire table in JSON I just want to return a few select data fields from the particular table so I don't download unnecessary data.

I know that you do this in the SELECT query but something is wrong with my syntax for this.

I had been trying with:

```
$query = "SELECT *[datafield],[otherdatafield],... FROM table";
```

but that doesnt seem to be working.

Also, In that table there are two separate data fields that are used to build a URL for an image, and Im not sure how to combine the two here so that they are returned in the JSON as one field.

For example: I Have a base string

```
"http://wwww.mysite.com/"
```

and i would like the add the two data Fields to that string so that when it returns the JSON objects they have those fields already concatenated so that the app can just use that URL:

```
"http://wwww.mysite.com/[data field1]/[datafield2]"
```

Comment: You use `$records[] = $r;` and thus the `$records` array gets reseted every fetched row, resulting in only the last row being json_encoded.

Comment: Try testing your sql in phpmyadmin or mysql workbench

Comment: @SpYk3HH oh sorry, i'm not that good in PHP.

Comment: Also, you should really look at using [`mysqli`](http://us2.php.net/mysqli)

Comment: @MichaelvdNet --you might delete your first comment? i removed my explanation, figured the extra fluff could be gotten rid of here. =--`This Message Will Self Destruct in *5 Minutes`--=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query to fetch individual cols is

```
select col1,col2,col3 from table_name
```

No need to provide * like you did

```
$query = "SELECT *[datafield],[otherdatafield],... FROM table";
                 ^........here * is causing the problem.
```

Comment: On top of the fact `*` will make it fail. I always use the little tilde thing around my column names myself. mainly like the clean look. `SELECT \`COLA\`, \`COLB\`, \`COLC\`, \`COLD\` FROM TABLE`

Comment: that is giving me the same error in my browser when i try to load it: This JSON file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
Array[0]

Comment: add header('Content-Type: text/json'); before the echo

Comment: try to do a print_r($records) of your data and see if the array has data before doing json_encode() this might tell you more.

Answer (score 2):

The query you should be trying looks like

> $query = "SELECT col1,col2 FROM table";// no need of asterisk if you mention col names

Now if you need to combine two columns there itself in the query, try something like

> $query = "SELECT  CONCAT('mysite.com/',col1,'/',col2) FROM table";

"/" is the separator between two columns.

Comment: thanks that worked, how to would I add my "http://www.mysite.com/" string to the beginning of that?